# Assigning one Variant to Another in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, variant, vba

So I have two (not adjacent) columns of data on my Excel worksheet, with different numbers of entries.  I load their data into two Variants called arr1 and arr2.  In the processing that follows, I want to refer to the columns with the fewest and most entries, so I define two Variant variables called shortArr and longArr, and assign arr1 and arr2 to them according to whose Ubound() is larger.  My questions are:

1. Is it legal to assign one Variant to another, like "shortArr = arr1"?
2. If it is, do the Variants need to have the same bounds first?
3. Will memory usage be doubled if I do this, or will shortArr and arr1 basically just be pointers to the same array?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Is it legal to assign one Variant to another, like "shortArr = arr1"?
> 2. If it is, do the Variants need to have the same bounds first?

Yes it is quite normal. You can assign till the time, the second array is not dimensioned.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim Arr1(1 To 2), Arr2()

    Arr1(1) = 2: Arr1(2) = 3

    Arr2 = Arr1
    MsgBox Arr2(2)
End Sub
```

> Will memory usage be doubled if I do this, or will shortArr and arr1 basically just be pointers to the same array?

Yes. They will be pointers to different array.

Comment: Thanks Siddharth!  I thought the second array would have to be dimensioned, but that's awesome that it doesnt.  Do you know if Arr1's contents are copied or not?

Comment: Check the last line `MsgBox Arr2(2)` ;)

Comment: oh okay.  Doubling the memory is annoying but I guess it saves me writing  nested loops everywhere.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Most of what you want can't be achieved in VBA without a loop:

[image]